# Gold bar inspection question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There is a vault containing (N) 10,000 gold bars.

A number of different bars (I) can be chosen at random and inspected for purity.  Assume all inspections come back indicating the bar inspected is pure.

How many inspections are needed to be able to say there is a 90% chance that 99.9% of the gold bars are pure?

Comment: There's not enough information to answer the question. We'd have to know your prior beliefs about how likely it is that the bars are pure. The only question we can answer with the information that you've given us so far is how many bars you'd need to inspect in order to say that the probability for a positive inspection result would be at most $10\%$ if at most $99.9\%$ of the bars were pure. That's a fundamentally different question from the one you're asking.

Comment: What have you tried?  Assume there are $11$ fake ones.  How many do you have to check to have a $90\%$ chance of finding one?

Comment: @RossMillikan  Assuming the fake bars are randomly distributed (from 1 to N) then one can assume a maximum expected fake bar number (for 11 it would be 11/12 or about 92%.  So, if one searches from N backwards, then you be expected to find a fake bar after about 100 inspections.

Comment: No, your chance of finding a fake on the first inspection is $11/10,000$.  Just compute the chance you don't find a fake in $n$ tries.  That will be a decreasing function of $n$.  How high does $n$ have to be to get it below $10\%$?

Comment: @RossMillikan Do you mean below 90%? About 96 tries.

Comment: No, we are computing the chance that you don't find one on the assumption that there are $11$ in the vault.  You want that chance to be less than $10\%$.  That would mean that $90\%$ of the time you would find at least one fake and declare that you did not pass the test.

Comment: 2000 checks would give about 11%  assuming .9989^2000.  I am not sure that is correct, though.

Comment: 2000 checks is not correct.  It is somewhat less than that.

Answer (score -2):

Let $M$ represent the number of impure golden bars in the vault. The relevant probability statement is $Pr[No\ impure\ bars\ after\ I\ inspections|M\leq10]\geq0.9$. Is there some way to simplify the left side of the equation in terms of the given variables? Then you should be able to solve for $I$.